# Problems with time using rosbag api

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!!

I have some problems using the rosbag api. Here I present some of my code:

```
rosbag::Bag bagR("bag.bag",rosbag::bagmode::Read);
rosbag::View view;
view.addQuery(bagR,rosbag::TopicQuery(_topics));
nav_msgs::Odometry msg;
BOOST_FOREACH(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view){
  ROS_INFO("T: %i.%i",m.getTime().sec,m.getTime().nsec);
  msg = *m.instantiate<nav_msgs::Odometry>();
  ROS_INFO("T: %i.%i",msg.header.stamp.sec,msg.header.stamp.nsec);
}
```

beeing _topics a vector of strings containg all the topics I need.

The problem is that the time from m.getTime() and the time from msg.header.stamp are different and I do not understand why that happends. Can somebody give me a hint on that?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86816/problems-with-time-using-rosbag-api/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2013-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The time of the message in the rosbag is the message receipt time not the timestamp of the payload(It may be purposefully in the past or future, or delayed by network lag.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0